# Parallel Structure Rules for possessive pronoun

Tags: parallelism

I was wondering if this is grammatically correct sentence based on parallel structure?

> After the families received complaints, their dogs were seized and they were fined 1,000 dollars.

Comment: It looks like maybe the dogs were fined.

Comment: The rules are (1) that the nearest plausible antecedent is seen **as** the antecedent and (2) the antecedent is not too far away. Only a wag might say the dogs might be fined here.

Comment: The sentence is correct and natural. The word "they" makes it clear that the families were fined. If it were the dogs who got fined, it would read, "... their dogs were seized and fined..."

Comment: After complaints were made about the families' dogs, the dogs were seized and the families were fined $1,000. That's better and avoids the issue of fining the dogs. Ha ha.

Comment: Who received the complaints?   Did "the family" receive the complaints, or did some authorities (presumably those that fined the families) receive the complaints?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is fine. I don't see any real problems with this sentence. (Perhaps it is a bit vague about whether the familes were fined $1,000 each or in total, etc., but there aren't any major issues.)